# Passing environment value with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I see this line in JS:

```
 const myKnex = require('knex')(config);
```

normally I would change it to TS with:

```
 import { myKnex } from 'knex';
```

but how can I add the **(config)** part?

Comment: I sure would like to know that too. That is one legit question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful as the two lines you mentioned are not equivalent. In the first case ("JS") you're importing the *default* export and then running it as a function, and saving the return value; in the second case you're importing an specific *named* export.

In any case, the first line would work like this, either in Typescript or modern JavaScript:

```
import knex from 'knex';
const myKnex = knex(config);
```

Answer (score 4):

One important thing to note when working with Node is that it developed its own [module system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) before ES6 modules came around.

The first line of code that you reference is using that module system, but it also is doing more than just loading the module. Knex is actually returning a function when you load the module, and **config** is being passed into that function. Another way to write this would be:

```
const knex = require('knex');
const myKnex = knex(config);
```

So, if you would want to use the ES6 module system (which is preferred when writing  TypeScript) to load knex, you could do something like:

```
import * as knex from 'knex';
const myKnex = knex(config);
```

From doing a little bit of digging into Knex as well, it does look like you need to use the **import * as** syntax and not **import knex from 'knex'** if you are working in TypeScript. Here is a thread that goes into that more: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/2189

The [TypeScript docs on modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) also cover all of the different use cases you might find yourself in. I think they're pretty helpful to have on hand.